# How to remove an element using range loop iterator

Tags: c++11, std, future

I'm trying to remove an element from

```
std::list<std::future<void>> my_list;
```

using

```
for(auto& itr:my_list) {
    if (/*something*/)
        my_list.erase(it)
}
```

doesn't work! I believe its because `std::future` is movable type. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This question shouldn't be tagged with "movabletype".  Movable Type is a Content Management System, similar to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a range-based for loop. Such a loop cannot be used to erase elements from the container. You could use `std::remove_if` instead:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), cond);
my_list.erase(new_end, my_list.end());
```

where `cond` is a function that returns `true` if the future should be removed:

```
bool cond(const std::future<void>& fut)
{
    if (/* something */)
        return true; // fut will be erased from list
    else
        return false; // fut will be kept in list
}
```

Comment: Is removed_if thread_safe? If the list is being updated from multiple threads, does it still work? Thanks!

Comment: @Pal: You need to do some sort of thread synchronization around your list; it won't be done for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`itr` is not an iterator, it is of type `std::future<void>`.

[`std::list::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) only accepts iterators, so you can't pass a value like `itr` to it. You will have to fall back to a normal iterator loop to do that.